# rsync --include is not working as expected

Tags: jenkins, rsync

I am trying to backup jenkins home directory (/home/ubuntu/.jenkins/) using rsync to the target directory /opt/jenbkup/. Since the directory traversal seems not working as expected, I have gone with single directory in the filter:

```
rsync -avr --include="jobs/*/config.xml" --exclude="*" /home/saga/.jenkins /opt/jenbkup
```

But nothing is copied. I also tried with exact file path in the include and did not work.

```
rsync -avr --include="jobs/job1/config.xml" --exclude="*" /home/saga/.jenkins /opt/jenbkup
```

File is not copied to destination. I don't understand whats wrong here. Some one please assist.

Comment: Thanks for asking. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume, that you would only backup the `config.xml` files in your `JENKINS_HOME`, then this should work:

```
rsync -av --include="*/" --include="config.xml" --exclude="*" \
      --delete --prune-empty-dirs /home/saga/.jenkins/ /opt/jenbkup/
```

Short explaination of the used options:

- `--include="*/"` traverse all directories
- `--include="config.xml"` include only files named "config.xml"
- `--exclude="*"` exlude everything
- `--delete` delete non-existing files in the backup
- `--prune-empty-dirs` delete empty directories from the backup

Comment: In this case, config.xml in other directories also will be copied, won't it? If so, this may not be ideal.
Any other approaches to accomplish this?

Comment: Appears that if the include option contains the full path to the `config.xml` file, only that file will be copied/backed up